# convergence functions calcultions

Tags: calculus, integration

Show that

1. $\displaystyle\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x^7e^x}$

   and
2. $\displaystyle\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2}$

are convergence.

I have no idea how to solve the first one but I think I know the second:

$$\begin{align}
\int_1^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x^2}
&= \int_1^{\infty} \frac{\sin(x)}{x \cdot x}
\\&=\int_1^{\infty} \frac{1}{x}
\\&=\lim\limits_{x \to M} \int_1^{M} \frac{1}{M}
\\&=\left[\frac{1}{x^2}\right]^M
\\&=\frac{1}{M^2}-\frac{1}{1}
\\&=\frac{1}{\infty^2}-1
\\&=0-1= 1
\end{align}$$

Am I right? And how to solve the first one?

Thanks

Comment: I don't think your argument for the second one is valid. How can you get the second equality?

Comment: Compare with the convergent integral  $\int_1^\infty e^{-x}\,dx$. Or with $\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^7}\,dx$.

Comment: X^2 = X*X and sinx/x is 1.

Comment: @AndréNicolas why only with one of them? and what about the second?

Comment: It doesn't matter which one you compare with. On our interval, each function is less than or equal to your function.

Comment: @momd $(\sin x)/ x\neq1$. Are you thinkng about $\lim_{x\to0}(\sin x)/x=1$?

Comment: @TheGreatSeo - oh yes, my mistake. So how do you solve also this one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For **1**, since $e^{-x}<1$ on $(1,\infty)$,
$$\left|\frac{1}{x^7e^x}\right|<{1\over x^7},$$
and $\int_1^\infty{1\over x^7}$ obviously converges.

For **2**, since $|\sin x|\le1$,
$$\left|{\sin x\over x^2}\right|\le{1\over x^2},$$
and $\int_1^\infty {1\over x^2}$ obviously converges.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:
$$
|\int_a^b f(x){\rm d}x|\le \int_a^b |f(x)|{\rm d}x
$$
and the fact that for $r\ne -1$, one have
$$
\int x^r{\rm d}x=\frac{1}{r+1}x^{r+1}.
$$

Comment: And what about the second?

Comment: Note that you need to prove just that the integrals are valid (convergent).

Comment: You mean for the 2th inegral?

Comment: @momd The Great Seo has completed my hint!